# Automatically start the necessary pdflatex runs if .tex has changed (MacOS X)?

Tags: tools, automation, mac, latexmk

I read about [`Latex Daemon`](http://william.famille-blum.org/software/latexdaemon/index.html), which seems to automatically start a new latex run, when the source document (.tex) has changed.

Can somebody recommend me a **similar solution for `MacOS X`** (as Latex daemon seems to be for `Windows` only)?

---

*snip:*
I've removed the 2nd part of my question about speeding things up and created a new question: [How to speed up pdflatex for a very large document on MacOS X?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15604/how-to-speed-up-pdflatex-for-a-very-large-document-on-macos-x)

---

I use `TexMakerX` as editor and `Skim`as viewer.
`Skim` can autoupdate the PDF file, as soon as it has changed, so that should be no problem.
My current LaTeX project has several source files, combined with `\include`, so the solution should be able to "observe" the changes of at least one of those files.

**edit:**

I'll accept `latexmk` as the answer for automatically running `pdflatex` several times to update bibliography and references
 and I'll ask the question of speeding up processing in a new question.

For those who want to set up `latexmk`on `MacOS X`, [this page from Damien Pollet](http://people.untyped.org/damien.pollet/notes/2010/latexmk-omnigraffle.html) could be helpful.

Problems I had with `latexmk`:

- with the `-pvc`-option it seems to slow down my MacBook, as switching to another application got quite slow, especially when its windows were located in another Space
- so I turned that off and just now use `latexmk` via short key `F1` to automatically compile "everything", while I use a single `pdflatex`-run with `F2` to add small changes in the text.

While searching with google I also found the `atchange` program http://www.ccrnp.ncifcrf.gov/~toms/atchange.html which seems to do similar things, I did not test it yet.

Comment: MacOS X has Automator and Folder Actions which can be used to execute shell scripts when files have changes. However, I haven't tried this for `pdflatex` and can only suggest to look into this.

Comment: @Christian Lindig: interesting idea!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`latexmk`](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) can run in automatic-update mode using the `-pvc` option:

```
# latexmk -pdf -pvc file.tex
```

It is a Perl script, so it should run under any OS as long a Perl compiler is installed. I'm not sure, but I think TeXLive ships with one, at least under Windows I think.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Thank you, that answers part 1 of my question. `latexmk` was part of my `TeXLive` installation, I've already tried it and it works very well so far! Here are some useful tips for configuration on MacOS which helped me setting it up very quickly (also automatically using synctex): http://people.untyped.org/damien.pollet/notes/2010/latexmk-omnigraffle.html - so now there is only the speed issue left :-(

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: the automatic-update mode with `-pvc` seemed very promising, but since then I had problem with the responsiveness when changing `spaces` (virtual desktops in `OS X`) - it took extremely long to change to another space or application. As soon as I quit `latexmk` this was gone, so I fear this might be a side effect :-(
Nevertheless I can use `latexmk` as my primary command for typesetting not to have launch pdflatex several times.

Answer (score 2):

Claus Gerhardt's [FlashMode](http://web.me.com/gerhardt/Flashmode/) does this, but for TeXShop.

Comment: Thanks, Alan. That looks very promising too, but unfortunately I don't want to switch back to TeXShop for some good reasons. :-(

Answer (score 2):

During searching in the internet, I also found [`atchange`](http://www.ccrnp.ncifcrf.gov/~toms/atchange.html) which seems to also be able to automatically detect changes in any specified text document and then run predefined shell scripts.

Taken from the homepage [1](http://www.ccrnp.ncifcrf.gov/~toms/atchange.html):

> When the atchange program is running, it watches one or more files. When any of those files changes, the atchange program will wake up and do any actions you want. Tasks such as modifying and compiling a program, modifying a data file and using it, or editing a text and typesetting it can be automated with a single typed command such as:
>   atchange myprogram "compile myprogram"
>   By setting up atchange once before starting a repetitive task, one can avoid hundreds of mouse movements.

(I did not test it yet)

Comment: Thanks, I was actually looking for some general tool like this.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: freut mich, wenn ich auch mal helfen konnte. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done with *fswatch* as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac):

```
# Install with brew
brew install fswatch
```

And run for a file, for example *filename.tex*:

```
fswatch -o filename.tex | xargs -n1 -I{} pdflatex filename.tex
```