# How to speed up pdflatex for a very large document on MacOS X?

Tags: pdftex, mac

I wonder how I can speed up the `pdflatex` compilation of a large document (thesis) with >200 pages and many images (however all imported PDFs or imported pixel graphics, no `TikZ`or similar things yet!).
My current LaTeX project has several source files, combined with `\include`.

I read about [`latexdaemon`](http://william.famille-blum.org/software/latexdaemon/index.html) which seems to be able to precompile the preamble to save time.

- Is there anything similar I can use on `MacOS X`?
- Are there ways to only process the things that have really changed? (I'm currently editing many chapters at the same time, so `\includeonly` seems not helpful.)

I use `TexMakerX` as editor and `Skim`as viewer.
I've configured `latexmk` to automatically do several `pdflatex` runs (see [Automatically start the necessary pdflatex runs if .tex has changed (MacOS X)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15342/automatically-start-the-necessary-pdflatex-runs-if-tex-has-changed-macos-x)).

`Skim` does autoupdate the PDF file, as soon as it has changed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take a look [this description](https://web.archive.org/web/20150406152732/https://magic.aladdin.cs.cmu.edu/2007/11/02/precompiled-preamble-for-latex/). It's a description of how to format the preamble yourself. Assuming your source file is `main.tex`, it all comes down to these steps (which were copied from the link and modified by me for my own use):

1. Rearrange your preamble so that its static part precedes any dynamic part. What in the preamble can be “*dynamic*”? For example, if you use `\includeonly`, you probably want to change its argument rather frequently and so it is not static. Finally, some packages read and write auxiliary files when you issue a command that you should put in the preamble (eg, `nomencl` uses `\makenomenclature`). Clearly, you have to run these
   commands in every run.
2. Extract the static part of the preamble into, say, `preamble.tex`. At this point, `main.tex` no longer contains the static part. It should start with the dynamic part, or simply `\begin{document} if you have nothing dynamic.
3. Execute:

   ```
   pdflatex -ini -jobname="preamble" "&pdflatex preamble.tex\dump"
   ```

in the command line. You will notice that a new file `preamble.fmt has
been generated in the same directory, along with other auxiliary files.

4. Edit the first line of main.tex so that it starts with `%&preamble`.
5. Execute latex `main.tex` as usual:

   ```
   pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex
   ```

You may get an error about the class file immediately, or you may notice that latex finishes as usual. But if you have paid attention to the output, or if you inspect the the log file, then you will see that the preamble gets processed in “no time” at all. At this point, cheers!

To make things slightly fancier, here is an modification. First, add this to the end of `preamble.tex`:

```
\def\preambleloaded{Precompiled preamble loaded.}
```

Then, before the dynamic preamble (or `\begin{document}` if there is none) of
`main.tex, add:

```
\def\ifundefined#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax} \ifundefined{preambleloaded}
\typeout{PRECOMILED PREAMBLE NOT LOADED}\input{preamble} \else
\typeout{\preambleloaded}
\fi
```

The idea is to define a macro in the precompiled preamble and use it to detect if the precompiled preamble has been loaded or not. If not, \input{preamble} will be used to pull the static preamble back in and you will not see any error at all.

---

Also, if you are using `tikz` to make figures, have a look at the `external` library. Check [the Tikz and Pgf manual](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), section 32 describes how to use it.

Comment: @romeovs: thank you for your help/explanation (sorry for my late reply)! Thant looks interesting, however I tried to copy all the preamble with begin and end document (but without the document) to a new file and compiled it once with pdflatex. That took 1 second. Does that mean I'll save only one second each latex run, if I follow the instructions above? When I launch latexmk, I assume the preamble is compiled only once, or is it compiled ad each pdflatex run? What stopped me from trying it diretcly was: I'm not sure which of my commands in the preamble could be dynamic - how do I find out?

Comment: @Martin I don't know if you can add up the compilation time of `preamble` and `main` to get the standard compilation time. Als, I don't use `latexmk` and therefore do not know what it does exactly, my guess is that it only compiles `preamble.tex` once. You could check this by constructing a very bulky preamble and running that several times, looking for speed changes. As for dynamic commands, I just meant the commands that you might alter a lot when working in `main.tex` (eg. a macro that might change). Macro's that edit auxiliary files should also be considered dynamic (as mentioned above).

Comment: @romeovs: thanks for your answer. So I assume, that it could really save me "only" 1 second per latex run? Considering the fact that I now spent about half an hour to figure out the effects of the precompiled preamble and `draftmode`, ... :-(  The problem with the dynamic commands is: I'm not sure which of them might modify .aux files and before I spend much time for finding out, it might be the better choice to just go on writing my thesis. :-(

Comment: @Martin Yes, when you have a small preamble it won't actually save you much time. I use a large preamble with lot's of packages and self-defined macro's, package options etc. Using this method I can knock 7 to 8 seconds of my compiler time, which is quit neat. I use quite a lot of packages and none of them use auxiliary files in the preamble, so I'd say the chances are that your packages don't do this either. It's a safe bet to place none of them in the dynamic preamble. If something behaves strange you can always move them.

Comment: In fact I only use `\tikzexternalize` in my dynamic preamble, because I might change it's options from time to time, that's all.

Comment: @romeovs: thanks for your remarks. IMHO my preamble is also quite lengthy and uses many packages and self defined commands, so I wonder if my test (compiling only this preamble as a separate file) is really "representative". If you copy your preamble to an empty tex file and add and empty document with `\begin{document}  \end{document}`, does it also take 8s to compile this file with `pdflatex`?

Comment: @romeovs: Thanks for this nice answer! It’s a nice feature but I had to replace `"&latex preamble.tex\dump"` width `"&pdflatex preamble.tex\dump"` because I have JPG-images. May you’d like to add a nota abut this to your answer.

Answer (score 9):

for all except the last `pdflatex` run use `-draftmode`

```
pdflatex -draftmode file
```

*taken from the documentation:*

> ```
>    -draftmode
>           Sets \pdfdraftmode so pdfTeX doesn't write  a  PDF  and  doesn't
>           read any included images, thus speeding up execution.
> ```

Comment: I already use the option `draft` in the `fixme`-Package, is that the same? -- and. with "last run" do you mean the last run of those in `latexmk` each time, or only "the one" very last run to produce the final document?

Comment: I am talking about an option for pdflatex and not of a package option. The last run is the last pdflatex run.

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks! I just knew about the package options and wondered if they just might activate the corresponding option for `pdflatex`. For the "last run": I hope I did not misunderstand you, so how can I tell `latexmk` to use `-draftmode` for all runs except the last one?

Comment: `pdflatex` is already running when reading the package options and `-draftmode` is far different to a `draft` option. Look into the latexmk or write to the author, that he should take the option into account.

Comment: see also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8317/how-to-cause-unix-make-to-know-how-many-times-to-run-tex

Comment: @Herbert: thanks again for your help! I tried it out: if I use `-draftmode` as an option for `latexmk` (always), it takes **33s** to compile (always after removing all aux files etc.) my 260 pages thesis, instead of **46s** without draftmode, but then in the first case, I have no PDF to preview. Unfortunately, it seems not possible to disable draftmode only in the last run, as `latexmk`does not know it will be the last run (that's what the author wrote me). If I do `latexmk` with draftmode and then add one "normal" `pdflatex` run, it also takes **45s**.

Comment: +1! That is really amazing: 43s instead of 138s for one compilation run of the current version of my thesis. Because I compile it by calling a script, which also calls `makeindex`, I was able to just add `-draftmode` to all but the last run. That saves a lot of time!

Answer (score 9):

Setting in the preamble

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
```

reduced the compile time for my (current version of my) thesis from 2:05 to 1:01 (Minutes:Seconds), but also increased the size of the pdf from about 65 MB to 718 MB (seven hundred eighteen Megabyte). Therefore for the final pdflatex run probably

```
\pdfminorversion=4% or 5 or 6...
\pdfcompresslevel=9% which is really slooow
\pdfobjcompresslevel=3% maybe reduce to 2; 3 might not be supported by all readers
```

should be used. If you use a version control system making (uncompressed) backups also of the pdf, you should think about what to do with the 718 MB files...