# How to properly 'make' a latex project?

Tags: makefile

I've got a latex project that looks like this:

```
project/
   |-- main.tex
   |-- main.bib
   |-- preamble.tex
   |-- preamble.fmt
   |-- makefile
```

The preamble (`preamble.tex`) is being precompiled into `preamble.fmt`. `main.bib` is generated using the `file contents` environment in `main.tex`.

This is what is in my `makefile`

```
TEX = pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error
PRE =  $(TEX) -ini -job-name="preamble" "&pdflatex preamble.tex\dump"
BIB = bibtex

.PHONY: all view

all : main.pdf

view :
    open main.pdf

main.pdf : main.tex preamble.fmt main.bbl main.blg
    $(TEX) main.tex

main.bbl main.blg : main.bib main.aux
    $(BIB) main

main.aux : main.tex
    $(TEX) main.tex

main.bib : main.tex
    $(TEX) main.tex

preamble.fmt : preamble.tex
    $(PRE) preamble.tex
```

The problem is here that `bibtex` relies on `main.aux` to be generated, and `main.aux` is regenerated every `pdftex` run. This leads to regeneration of the bibtex files every run, which causes makefile to run `$(TEX) main.tex` a second time (it thinks the `.bbl` and `.blg` files are changed, because it looks at their edit time).

So, basically every time I call `make all` latex is compiled twice, even if there are no changes to references made anywhere in the document (thus making this unnecessary).

Is there a way I can tell `make` that it only compiles twice if there is an actual *change* to the `.aux` and the `.bib` files. Perhaps by checking of md5 sums?

I'm kind of new to the whole makefile thing, so I thought I'd ask here. It could be off-topic, but I thought the latex gurus that reside on this site might have an answer.

Comment: Have you considered `rubber`, `latexmk` or similar tools? Also, why are you building a format?

Comment: I only saw after posting the question that there is the `{makefile}` tag, which I'm now scanning for useful code. I'll leave this question up for now.

Comment: @JosephWright The format is nice because I only need to compile the preamble once, which save me a lot of compiling time. See for instance [this answer I once posted](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15606/3127). I'm looking into these alternatives now, but I'm integrating some other stuff too (like `c++` code that generates data which I input into the tex file) and I don't know if that can be easily done using `latexmk` or `rubber`.

Comment: Don't add `main.aux` to the dependencies of `$(BIB)` (I don't know if its the right terminology).

Comment: @egreg this won;t do, because `bibtex` does need the `main.aux` file to be present. Either way, I still would need to compile `main.tex` before `bibtex` is run to see if `main.bib` (which is generated in the `main.tex` run) has changed. The problem is in how `make` checks if a file has changed. Perhaps this question should be migrated to the Stack Overflow site?

Comment: If you can offer some sample code for this case, I could try and see how scons copes with it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240037/recommended-build-system-for-latex

Answer (score 187, accepted):

`latexmk` is the answer you are looking for.

LaTeX is notoriously difficult to "get right" using a Makefile, because it might take multiple compiler passes - updating e.g. `.aux` files - to get the finished results. Getting this right in a *general* Makefile (as opposed to one tailored to a specific document) is very hard, which is why there are pre-made solutions. Of these, `latexmk` comes included with your average LaTeX distribution, which is why I consider it first choice.

The trick is to provide a Makefile rule for every custom step x-to-TeX (or x-to-PDF or whatever) you might have, and having `latexmk` figure out all the LaTeX-related stuff while relying on the Makefile for the rest (via `-use-make`).

```
# You want latexmk to *always* run, because make does not have all the info.
# Also, include non-file targets in .PHONY so they are run regardless of any
# file of the given name existing.
.PHONY: MyDoc.pdf all clean

# The first rule in a Makefile is the one executed by default ("make"). It
# should always be the "all" rule, so that "make" and "make all" are identical.
all: MyDoc.pdf

# CUSTOM BUILD RULES

# In case you didn't know, '$@' is a variable holding the name of the target,
# and '$<' is a variable holding the (first) dependency of a rule.
# "raw2tex" and "dat2tex" are just placeholders for whatever custom steps
# you might have.

%.tex: %.raw
        ./raw2tex $< > $@

%.tex: %.dat
        ./dat2tex $< > $@

# MAIN LATEXMK RULE

# -pdf tells latexmk to generate PDF directly (instead of DVI).
# -pdflatex="" tells latexmk to call a specific backend with specific options.
# -use-make tells latexmk to call make for generating missing files.

# -interaction=nonstopmode keeps the pdflatex backend from stopping at a
# missing file reference and interactively asking you for an alternative.

MyDoc.pdf: MyDoc.tex
        latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make MyDoc.tex

clean:
        latexmk -CA
```

This setup works flawlessly for anything referenced via `\include`.

However, `\include` might not be appropriate in every case. For one, it is not nestable (i.e. an `\include`d file may not `\include` another). It also adds an automatic `\clearpage` to your document, i.e. `\include`d content starts a new page. It also has advantages, like resulting in shorter re-build times if contents are modified, but sometimes you need nesting, or the referenced file's contents should be embedded in a page.

You need `\input` for this.

Sadly, `\input` breaks the build. If `pdflatex` encounters a missing `\input` file, it generates an *error* (instead of a warning like with `\include`), and stops compiling. Yes, `latexmk` will generate the file and re-start `pdflatex`, but this is inefficient, and breaks completely if you have multiple such file references, because eventually the compile will end with a "too many re-runs" message.

[John Collins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40924/6832)' answer to a question by me regarding this problem provides a workaround:

```
\newcommand\inputfile[1]{%
    \InputIfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}%
}
```

This macro generates a *warning* instead of the *error* of a straight `\input`, and allows `latexmk` to generate all missing files in the first pass.

**Note:** A rule with the generic target `%.pdf: %.tex` gives you trouble once you start using `\includeonly` in your document, for reasons internal and complex. That's why I used a specific rule instead of a generic one.

---

There is actually one alternative to `latexmk` that I can also recommend. In case you are looking at a more involved project setup, you might consider [CMake](http://www.cmake.org), for which Kenneth Moreland has done the excellent [UseLATEX.cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/kmorel/UseLATEX) module.

This, however, is a bit too involved to give a how-to in the scope of this answer.

Comment: haha, this actually works! sweet. I'm going to mess around with it a bit and probably accept! +1

Comment: since `latexmk` apparently doesn't know about the pre formatted preamble. I needed to do `main.pdf: preamble.fmt`. Otherwise all is fine!

Comment: 1. Actually, if you turn the recorder option on in `latexmk`, it does know about the format file.  2. If you are using a makefile, it's a good idea to have all the source files listed in the makefile.  `Latexmk` can set this up automatically; see the section "USING `latexmk` WITH `make`" in the `latexmk` documentation.

Comment: @romeovs: Please note the complete overhaul of the answer. Thanks to John Collins, it now includes a fully functional example.

Comment: @JohnCollins: I hope the link gets you lots of upvotes. **Thank you** for that macro solution!

Comment: MyDoc.pdf is a real file being produced---you shouldn't be listing it as `.PHONY`.

Comment: @uckelman: `MyDoc.pdf` is not only depending on `MyDoc.tex`, as the Makefile states, but also on the various generated / included files. Only `latexmk` knows which ones that would be. So we need to run `latexmk` in any case so it can inspect if anything important has changed. You can use certain `latexmk` options to embed its dependency logic into the Makefile, but I did not do this in my example for simplicity's sake. Listing `MyDoc.pdf` in `.PHONY` is therefore the right thing to do; `latexmk` will return immediately if nothing needs updating.

Comment: I guess it makes more sense to me to use dep files as described in `latexmk`'s man page, since it's only a few lines in the Makefile.

Comment: @uckelman: Maybe. The Makefile posted was basically verbatim what I used myself at that time (and still use), with comments added. At some point I'm happy to leave "well enough" alone, especially when considering a tradeoff between "simple" and "polished" in a SE answer. Including dependency files isn't that easy to explain, and somewhat OT for tex.SE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have another problem could you look at [it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172540/latex-project-together-with-sublime-text-2)? It is in the comments to my question.

Comment: So, I have come to a solution and posted it to my [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172540/latex-project-together-with-sublime-text-2/173657#173657).

Comment: Is `latexmk` also usefull when you have `Rnw` files for `R` / `knitr` in the project?

Comment: @buhtz: I have no knowledge about R / knitr. Can you put those into a `make` rule? Then yes.

Comment: It looks I am trying to achieve something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61279162/automate-latex-compilation-in-bash-by-getting-changed-tex-files-from-git). Is it better to use latexmk, basic make or bash+git to compile Tex files in a project?

Comment: @hhh: IMHO, version control (git/svn) and building should be two completely separate steps. Consider a build from an exported working directory, or a build made after your origin repo went the way of the Dodo. Or a build that runs on sources intentionally different from what is in the repo. A build should still be possible, and not change the sources present. I.e., trying to get git involved in this is a bad idea IMHO.

Comment: @DevSolar I want to save time, not wanting to compile each single page of large project, just the changed parts. Does latexmk avoid unnecessary compilation?

Comment: @hhh It avoids unnecessary recompilation *where possible*. You can help with that by modularizing your document, or by compiling only the subsection you are currently interested in (`\includeonly`). But that would be a different question.

Comment: @DevSolar I compiled everything with latexmk and some python, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61279831/164148). It was a nuisance to try to get Makefile work with Bash and LatexMk, so decided to go with Python. I had some problems with enviroment variables in Bash that I do not have in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by the way, what do `%.tex: %.raw` and `%.tex: %.dat` do? I commented them out and the make still works.

Comment: @zyy: They are placeholders, showcasing how you would add any custom steps that generate LaTeX source from some other input. If you don't have any of those, just leave the lines out.

Comment: @DevSolar I see, so those rules generate `.tex` files that may be included by `MyDoc.tex`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

### Publicly Available Makefiles for TeX Projects

Here're some good examples of makefiles for TeX projects. Feel free to add more.

#### By Matthias Vallentin

License: CC BY-NC-SA 4.0

Link: https://github.com/mavam/stat-cookbook/blob/master/Makefile

Includes `input` directives, standalone figures, bibliography, `latexmk`, and reruns. Part of the `stat-cookbook` repository, which gives some context how things work together.

#### By Yannick Copin

License: Not mentioned

Link: https://web.archive.org/web/20061205102406/http://snovae.in2p3.fr/ycopin/soft/Makefile.latex

Batch processing of `.tex` files, including bibliography. Supports reruns without `latexmk`.

#### By Chris Rost

License: Not mentioned

Link: https://stuff.mit.edu/people/jcrost/latexmake.html

#### By Kyle Woerner et al.

License: Not mentioned

Link (page 5): https://oceanai.mit.edu/k_w/latex_lab/lab_latex_8.pdf

#### By Petter Kallstrom

License: CC BY-SA 3.0

Link: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Make/Examples

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer [to a similar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318569). Features:

- Shows how to use checksum files with controlled timestamps where necessary.

  - There, it's not `.aux` to `.bbl` but index files `.nlo` to `.nls`,
    but you get the idea.
- Alternatively recommends [`latexmk`](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk).

  - Shows how to use `latexmk` with automatic dependency tracking
    in a GNU Makefile.
  - Example configuration `latexmkrc` for custom `makeindex` files
    as used by the `nomencl` package.

Have fun.

Answer (score 2):

One trick I use when calling (pdf)latex from a regular `Makefile` is to check in a shell `while` loop with `grep` the %.log file for the presence of the string `Rerun to get`, to ensure the required number of reruns of LaTeX to resolve all references.

My `Makefile` typically starts out like this:

```
# requires GNU make
SHELL=/bin/bash

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

%.pdf %.aux %.idx: %.tex
    pdflatex $<
    while grep 'Rerun to get ' $*.log ; do pdflatex $< ; done
%.ind: %.idx
    makeindex $*
%.bbl: %.aux
    bibtex $*
%.pdftex %.pdftex_t: %.fig
    fig2dev -L pdftex_t -p $*.pdftex $< $*.pdftex_t
    fig2dev -L pdftex $< $*.pdftex
```

Where things get tricky are rules involving %.aux as a dependency, which can lead to circular dependencies.