# latexmk: Multiple custom-generated files and \input

Tags: latexmk

Referring to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40738/how-to-properly-make-a-latex-project/40759#40759), I found that having multiple custom-generated files in a document generated by `latexmk` doesn't really work for me.

The modus operandi is that `latexmk` runs `pdflatex`, checking that noteable's output for missing file errors, then generating that file, then re-running `pdflatex`.

However, I have *many* files to be generated this way, and every pass of the above process only generates *one* of them (then re-running, finding the next missing file, generating *that*, rerunning... until `latexmk` gives up due to too many re-runs.)

Apparently I am doing something wrong, am missing a crucial command-line option or somesuch. But perusing the manual didn't enlighten me. Help, please?

**Edit:** I am aware that I could just use a common Makefile rule to generate those files outside the control of `latexmk`, with the document depending on those generated files. But I would like to know how it could be done *without* adding the dependencies to the Makefile, either manually or by having `latexmk` print Makefile rules, through `-use-make` or `add_cus_dep`()` or somesuch.

**Edit2:** A MWE for this:

Makefile:

```
test.pdf:
    latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make test.tex

%.tex:
    echo "Foo" > $@

clean:
    rm foo* test.pdf
```

test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\input{foo1}
\input{foo2}
\input{foo3}
\input{foo4}
\input{foo5}
\input{foo6}

\end{document}
```

**Edit3:** As a sidenote, `latexmk -CA` does not remove the files that *are* generated, either. There is a message of "*checking foo1.log for generated files*", but `foo1.tex` remains, which isn't what I would expect from a "clear *all*" option...

**Edit4: This only happens with `\input`.** If I use `\include` in the MWE above, everything works as I would expect: All custom file generation happens in the first pass. How can I get that behaviour with `\input`, too?

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal example where `latexmk` fails doing what you want?

Comment: @N.N.: Done....

Comment: Could you please explain what happens when you make the MWE and what you would like to happen? The clearer you are the greater are your chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: @N.N.: I think I've been pretty clear. Observed behaviour: `pdflatex` is re-run after every single generated file, eventually ending in a "too many re-runs" error message. Desired behaviour: All files being generated, ideally in a single pass instead of re-starting after each file (re performance), and the PDF eventually being created successfully.

Comment: @N.N.: Please note Edit4 above - this seems to be specific to files referred to via `\input`, with `\include` working as expected.

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include will help with that aspect. Please note that there is no reason to add Edit# all over your posts. It is easier to read your question (and hopefully help you) if you write is one coherent question rather than piling up explicit edits.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you look carefully at the output from the run, you'll see that on the first run, `pdflatex` detects a first missing file.  Since nonstopmode is being used, that causes a fatal error, and `pdflatex` goes no further.  Then `latexmk` sees a message about a single missing file, makes it, and repeats the run.  Then an error comes up about the second missing file, etc, with the annoying phenomenon you observed.  The situation is different when `\include` is used instead of `\input`.  This macro behaves differently: the missing file is no longer a fatal error; instead there are messages in the log file for all the missing files, all on the first run.

There are two solutions.  One is to run `pdflatex` in its normal mode, where it will stop and ask you to correct the filename.  Just hitting the enter key will cause `pdflatex` to continue, ignoring the missing file.  To automate this, change the second line of your `Makefile` to

```
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="cat responses | pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make test.tex
```

where `responses` is a file containing many blank lines.

A more systematic solution is to replace `\input` by a macro which gives a warning instead of a fatal error when a file is missing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\inputA[1]{%
    \InputIfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}%
}
\begin{document}
\inputA{foo1}
\inputA{foo2}
\inputA{foo3}
\inputA{foo4}
\inputA{foo5}
\inputA{foo6}
\end{document}
```

I've used this trick quite a few times.

Comment: Ah... excellent. I'd daresay that this would be a nice feature to add to `pdflatex` - a mode where missing `\input` files aren't fatal, so that `latexmk` could do its thing.

Comment: Took me a while to find this answer while trying to solve [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426458/use-latexmk-with-use-make-to-generate-standalone-graphics/426502). Since @JohnCollins is the owner of `latexmk`: Wouldn't this trick be worth mentioning in the official doc?

Comment: Note that your `\inputA` macro is exactly equivalent to LaTeX's internal `\@input@` macro.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by John Collins outlines well the reasons for the problem. Here is an update on his fix. Change the line of your Makefile to

```
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="yes '' | pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make test.tex
```

This eliminates the need for an dummy file (and it what `yes` was designed for).