# latexmk: generated tex file (via custom add_cus_dep) not found in first pass

Tags: latexmk

I have a latexmk-based project that uses some generated tex files included via `\input`. I'm generating these files using a latexmkrc file.

```
# latexmkrc
$cleanup_includes_cusdep_generated=1;           # clean generated .tex files                                                                                                                                                        

add_cus_dep('bar', 'tex', 0, 'touchtex');
sub touchtex {
    return system("cp $_[0].bar $_[0].tex");
}
```

A minimal working example tex project is.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
hello \input{foo}
\end{document}

% foo.bar
world
```

When I build the project with `latexmk -pdf` the first pass chokes because `foo.tex` doesn't exist yet.

Ultimately, the pdf is built correctly, but I have to `return` through each missing file. Can anyone explain how to suppress this prompt for tex files that are going to be generated via a `add_cus_dep` custom build command.

Comment: PS: using `\include` instead of `\input` doesn't have the same file-not-found problem.

Comment: This looks a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40850/15925 .  If that helps you, let us know and we will close this question.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. There is a workaround there for this problem.