# Use latexmk with -use-make to generate standalone graphics

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, makefile

I'm trying to build my `main.tex` that includes a standalone `pic.pdf`. Special is, that `pic.pdf` needs to be built by `latexmk` (via the `-use-make` flag) while actually building `main.tex`.

The problem appears to be, that the `latexmk` invocation for `main.tex` stops after building `pic.pdf` through make. Log output states due to errors, though `pic.pdf` was built fine before.

Here is my MWE:

---

**`Makefile`**

```
main.pdf: main.tex
    latexmk -interaction=nonstopmode -pdf -use-make -M -MP -MF $(@:.pdf=.d) $<

pic.pdf: pic.tex
    latexmk -interaction=nonstopmode -pdf -M -MP -MF $(@:.pdf=.d) $<

-include main.d
-include pic.d

clean:
    find . -not -name "*.tex" -not -name Makefile -delete
```

---

**`main.tex`**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]\includegraphics{pic.pdf}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

**`pic.tex`**:

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \tikz \fill [orange] (0,0) rectangle (6,2);
\end{document}
```

---

To reproduce the problem, run

```
make clean && make
```

This stops with an error after building `main.pdf` and `pic.pdf`, but should actually just re-build `main.pdf` once again and everything should be fine.

**Question**: How can I configure `latexmk` to re-try building `main.pdf` after its requirement `pic.pdf` has (successfully) been generated?

For the reference, here my log output (manually shortened; omitted stuff indicated via `[...]`):

```
[...]
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -interaction=nonstopmode -recorder  "main.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
[...]
LaTeX Warning: File `pic.pdf' not found on input line 5.
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `pic.pdf' not found.
[...]
l.5  \includegraphics{pic.pdf}
[...]
===========Latexmk: Missing input file: 'pic.pdf' from line
  'LaTeX Warning: File `pic.pdf' not found on input line 5.'
Latexmk: Missing input file: 'pic.pdf' from line
  'LaTeX Warning: File `pic.pdf' not found on input line 5.'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'main.pdf'
------------
Running 'make "pic.pdf"'
------------
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: 'pdflatex': source file 'pic.pdf' doesn't exist. I'll try making it...
make[1]: Entering directory '...'
[...]
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -interaction=nonstopmode -recorder  "pic.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Output written on pic.pdf (1 page, 1116 bytes).
[...] (no errors, everything fine)
Transcript written on pic.log.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'pic.pdf'
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: All targets (pic.pdf) are up-to-date
make[1]: Leaving directory '...'
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'main.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
make: *** [Makefile:2: main.pdf] Error 12
```

In case of interest, I'm using the following versions of contributing components:

```
latexmk:  Latexmk, John Collins, 19 Jan. 2017. Version 4.52c
pdflatex: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/TeX Live for SUSE Linux)
make:     GNU Make 4.2.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `latexmk` thinks the error

```
Package pdftex.def Error: File `pic.pdf' not found.
```

is non recoverable. To bypass that, we can include `pic.pdf` iff it exists and print a warning for `latexmk` otherwise. More precisely, after changing the `main.tex` in the MWE to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
 \IfFileExists{pic.pdf}{\includegraphics{pic.pdf}}{\typeout{No file pic.pdf.}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

the problem is resolved: `make clean && make` finishes without errors after building `main.pdf` twice. In the first round, the file doesn't yet exist, but we still compile fine and only print a message on the missing file.

(In the real world you will probably define a new command that handles the `\IfFileExists`.)

Idea taken from [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40850/latexmk-multiple-custom-generated-files-and-input) on `\input` (instead of `\includegraphics`). All credit to [@JohnCollins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8495/john-collins).