# Pendant to Textmate "Watch Document" function in Sublime Text LaTeXTools

Tags: sublime-text, textmate

I've been using TextMate and TextMate 2 for years writing LaTeX. I recently switched to Sublime Text, but still miss a key feature there.

The LaTeX package of TextMate 2 has the `Watch Document` function, which is "[...] a live pdf preview of the LaTeX document you're editing that automatically updates while you make changes." ([Source](http://jann.is/daily/archives/756-LaTex-Live-PDF-preview-with-TextMate-and-PDFView.html)).

These changes do not only include any Tex file included in a master document, but also extends to changes in images and other files included in the document.

I've already learned that it is possible in LaTeXTools for Sublime Text to build a project consisting of many files by including `%!TEX root = MyMasterFile.tex` on top of each document. However, I really do not like the tedious workflow of always triggering the build process by hand. I want LaTeXTools to rebuild my document as soon as any file associated with it changes.

My current workflow is triggering the `Watch Document` using Textmate 2 and then switching over to Sublime Text 3 to work on the project.

Is it possible to achieve this functionality with Sublime Text and LaTeXTools only?

Comment: You could always run `latexmk -pvc main` which will recompile whenever any file changes

Comment: This works exactly as I want it to. I've created a proper makefile using [this example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40759/79184). If you want to, you can add your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to simply launch `latexmk -pvc main` in your working directory. From the manual:

> **-pvc**   Run a file previewer  and  continually  update  the  .dvi,  .ps, and/or .pdf files whenever changes are made to source files (see the Description above).

`latexmk` is included in all modern TeX distributions.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just use a different ST plugin, like [`OnSaveBuild`](https://github.com/alexnj/SublimeOnSaveBuild) which would work if you change its `filename_filter` setting to something like `"\\.tex$"`.

Comment: This is a very good idea. The solution of @Bordaigorl, however, does exactly what I want and I think that his approach is more versatile.