# Makefile for a latex report

Tags: makefile

Not sure if this belongs here - but its bugging me.
I have a makefile :

```
DOCNAME=SI16-SC13B038
D1=Abstract
D2=Bonafide
D3=Declaration
D4=Introduction
DBIB=References

TEXDEP=$(D1)/*tex $(D2)/*tex $(D3)/*tex $(D4)/*tex

all: $(DOCNAME).pdf
$(DOCNAME).pdf: $(DOCNAME).tex $(TEXDEP) $(DOCNAME).nls $(DOCNAME).bbl
    pdflatex $(DOCNAME) && pdflatex $(DOCNAME)
$(DOCNAME).nls: $(DOCNAME).nlo
    makeindex $^ -s nomencl.ist -o $@
$(DOCNAME).nlo: $(DOCNAME).tex $(TEXDEP)
    pdflatex $(DOCNAME)
$(DOCNAME).bbl: $(DOCNAME).tex $(TEXDEP) $(DBIB)/*bib
    pdflatex $(DOCNAME) && bibtex $(DOCNAME)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.pdf *.bbl *.nlo *.nls
```

As can be seen, the current directory contains SI16-SC13B038.tex, which is the main tex file - there are other tex files in directories (stored in variables D1,D2,D3,D4) which are included in the main one.
I am using the nomencl package for nomenclatures and natbib for the bibliography (the references are in the directory name stored in DBIB).

The issue I am having is that the make file does not seem to evaluate dependencies - how many ever times I invoke make all the operations are done. Something's wrong with the makefile - help me out!

Comment: I am not sure this is on topic but I think your dependency `TEXDEP=$(DOCNAME).nlo ` should be `TEXDEP=$(DOCNAME).nls` as the nlo file is written out each time so newer than your source

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: well, the nlo and bbl files dont belong in TEXDEP - that's redundant - it still doesn seem to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly 'make' a latex project?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40738), though with slightly other specifics that discourage merging. My answer has been tuned to this question, but I have left a link at the other one now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle has indicated, if a `.nlo` gets recreated with each run,
this causes an update of the `.nls` target, then of the `.pdf` target.
But then `.nlo` has been updated again, so the cycle repeats every time
you invoke `make`.
To overcome that, you'd use a checksum file instead of the `.nlo` dependency,
and touch the checksum file only if the `.nlo` file contents have changed.
Here is an untested Makefile fragment:

```sh
$(DOCNAME).nls: $(DOCNAME).nlo-stamp
        makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o $@ $(DOCNAME).nlo

$(DOCNAME).nlo-stamp: $(DOCNAME).nlo
        sha1sum $^ >$@2
        if cmp -s $@2 $@; then rm $@2; else mv -f $@2 $@; fi
```

Replace your rule for `$(DOCNAME).nls` with that.

Do not forget to append `*.*-stamp` `*.*-stamp2` to the list of files to clean.

**Note:** If you copy-paste Makefile fragments, pipe them through `unexpand`
to regenerate the TAB characters.

---

Instead of the above, I'd suggest using
[`latexmk`](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk).
It does such things properly
and figures out all necessary program runs automatically.

With `latexmk`, a complete GNU Makefile generally looks like the following
(just tune `DOCNAME`):

```sh
# Tools
LATEXMK = latexmk
RM = rm -f

# Project-specific settings
DOCNAME = basename-of-your-main-document

# Targets
all: doc
doc: pdf
pdf: $(DOCNAME).pdf

# Rules
%.pdf: %.tex
        $(LATEXMK) -pdf -M -MP -MF $*.d $*

mostlyclean:
        $(LATEXMK) -silent -c
        $(RM) *.bbl

clean: mostlyclean
        $(LATEXMK) -silent -C
        $(RM) *.run.xml *.synctex.gz
        $(RM) *.d

.PHONY: all clean doc mostlyclean pdf

# Include auto-generated dependencies
-include *.d
```

This keeps track of dependencies automatically.
Even if only an installed and used package file has changed,
`make` triggers recompilation.

This is almost perfect. *Almost* because if you shadow a `texmf-dist` package
with a local one, the changed dependency path is not detected automatically.
It will however be recorded with the next TeX run.

To get the custom index files processed, add a `latexmkrc` file:

```perl
add_cus_dep('nlo', 'nls', 0, 'makenlo2nls');
sub makenlo2nls {
    system( "makeindex -o \"$_[0].nls\" -s nomencl.ist \"$_[0].nlo\"" );
}
```

BibTeX processing should work without extra configuration.

Comment: If it's helpful, I created a little GitHub repo for a generic Makefile that uses this method: https://github.com/schuster/latex-makefile

Answer (score 1):

Makefile is not exactly good for compiling TeX files. There is a special program LatexMk that does proper compilation and understands dependencies correctly. To use it as it is:
latexmk -pdf file.tex

If you really need to put it in a `Makefile`, the manual page for LatexMk gives the following recommendation:

```
.PHONY : all FORCE_MAKE
all : talk.pdf

%.pdf: %.tex FORCE_MAKE
    latexmk -pdf $<
```

The phony target `FORCE_MAKE` is used to force the target to always be built by Make such that LatexMk is actually invoked. Then you do not have to specify dependencies in complex TeX documents by yourself and still use Make to compile your document.