# What is makefile and when do I need to use it along with latexmk?

Tags: latexmk, makefile

I was looking for a tool that can look for changes in my TeX files then compiles them whenever a change is registered. So, I came across `latexmk` and managed to make it do what I want.

However, I found some articles/questions combining `makefile` (which I don't understand its main use) and `latexmk` to compile the TeX project.

I would like to know what `makefile` is and when I need to use both `makefile` and `latexmk` instead of `latexmk` only.

---

### P.S.

`makefile` can be installed from the sources mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17158442/2849383).

Thanks for David Carlisle [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324982/when-do-i-need-to-use-makefile-along-with-latexmk#comment794207_324987) to understand how to properly call the `make` command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a quite general question, and so it'll be hard to write down a complete answer. I'll talk about when I use [Make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) and when I use `latexmk`.

`latexmk` is a tool for compiling `.tex` files, and not much else. However, it's good at determining which files depend on which other files: you don't need to provide a list, so `latexmk main` will only recompile when a dependency of `main.tex` has changed. `latexmk` will also compile files two or three times if needed (e.g. for bibliography, index, or hyperlink updates).

Make is much more general, but requires an explicit description of a file's dependencies and how to compile it. This information is provided in a file usually called `makefile`. Suppose `main` depends on `main.tex`, `macros.tex`, and `eggs.tex`, and that it sometimes needs to be compiled twice. Then, the makefile might like this:

```make
# example makefile

INPUTS = main.tex macros.tex eggs.tex
COMPILER = pdflatex --halt-on-error

main.pdf: $(INPUTS)
    $(COMPILER) main.tex
    $(COMPILER) main.tex
```

It's more work to manually specify the dependencies and compilation instructions, especially since they can change throughout a project. But Make's advantage is that it can execute any command. If your final file depends on running some statistical test and including the results in your document, Make can run the test. If your file contains code listings, `latexmk` doesn't know to watch them for changes, but you can update `$(INPUTS)` to include them if you're using Make.

Another use for Make is to automatically do something to your output files after compilation.

In summary, **Make is more complicated, but able to handle non-TeX dependencies, so use it only if you have non-TeX dependencies or need to do postprocessing.**

Examples of such dependencies:

- source code listings in a non-TeX language
- statistical graphs or statistical analyses that are automatically generated from data
- images that are automatically generated from inputs or data
- information obtained from the “outside world,” e.g. the user or the Internet

Examples of postprocessing:

- Converting the output PDF into an image
- Moving the output PDF into another directory
- Compressing the output PDF

Comment: Complete answer to the point. My final question, I don't know if I properly installed `makefile` or not, but when I tried to compile your MWE, I got this messgae: `Nothing to be done for 'Makefile'`. Can you help me on this or the way I should follow to install `makefile`?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou I would guess you did `make Makefile` just do `make` or if you want to specify the makefile explictly use `make -f Makefile` but `Makefile` is the default name so just `make`  would be normal

Comment: @David Carlisle, your guess is absolutely right. couldn't be happier :). I will add your note to the main question body.

Comment: `latexmk` can do anything: it can launch `biber` or `bibtext`, `makeglossaries` and `xindy`, `convert`... and `make` if required.

Answer (score 9):

> I would like to know what `makefile` is

The command `make` most often refers to [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/make.html) or [BSD make](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/1/make/).
Each variant has its merits;
the differences are for advanced uses not discussed here.
Regardless of which variant is used, `make` expects to find a file named
`Makefile` which contains recipes on what files (so-called *targets*) to build
from other files (so-called *dependencies*) and what commands to use for
building the targets.
`make` then figures out what targets need to be built or rebuilt
and issues the required commands.
Essential points:

- You have to write a `Makefile` with the needed recipes.
- `make` executes each rebuild command for a given target *at most once*.
  That is unfortunate for LaTeX document processing where e.g. several
  `pdflatex` runs may be needed.
- `make` detects changes in dependencies by looking at file last-written times.
  But every `pdflatex` run writes an `.aux` file, therefore the next
  `make` run will behave as if the `.aux` file had changed,
  regardless of whether its actual contents have changed or not.

So if you'd like to formulate a recipe that re-runs `pdflatex`
until `.aux` file contents do not change anymore,
this is not a straightforward thing to do with `make`.
With a lot of sophistication and some tricks,
it is [possible](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex-make)
to formulate a useful `Makefile`, but its recipes tend to look very
complicated.

`latexmk` is specialized for LaTeX-based document processing.
It knows how to employ the various `*tex` programs and auxiliary tools like
`bibtex`, `biber`, or `makeindex`.
It does not need a `Makefile`, it can repeat commands as needed,
and it detects changes by looking at file contents (actually checksums)
rather than last-written times.

> when I need to use both `makefile` and `latexmk` instead of `latexmk` only

[There is an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318595/43576)
proposing a `Makefile` fragment that causes `make` to do the equivalent
of `latexmk -pdf`. In fact, such a `make` will delegate the document
processing details to `latexmk -pdf` with some fancy options added.
So why use `make` at all then?

If you just want the functionality of `latexmk`, you do not need `make`.
However,

- You can add more recipes to the `Makefile` so that `make` can do
  more things than just processing LaTeX documents.
  Cf. [Arun's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324987/43576).
  I typically add recipes for compiling programs, running tests,
  producing illustrations, and the like.
- Users of open-source software universally *expect* that `make`
  will build the files they want. By providing a suitable `Makefile`,
  this expectation is met.
- `make` is shorter to type.
  If you recompile frequently, such things matter.

If the above reasons do not appeal to you, you might sum those up as:

**`make` with `latexmk` is for users already accustomed to `make`
who recognize the utility of `latexmk`.**

Comment: _So why use make at all then?_ because make can run recursively  over the whole source tree updating each directory as it travels.  This can't be done using latexmk.  That is why using latexmk inside make make sense.