# latexmk and Makefile with multiple sources

Tags: latexmk, makefile

I have a main source file that `\include` a lot of other LaTeX files such as tables all named `tab-XXX.tex`. This way, I can have an appending that lists all the tables but this is beyond the point.

How do I set up the Makefile to automatically collect all `.tex` files so any changes cause the right build commands?

My Makefile is shamelessly taken from [ccorn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/43576/ccorn)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318595/6928):

```
# Tools
LATEXMK = latexmk
RM = rm -f

# Project specific settings
DOCNAME = main

# Targets
all: doc
doc: pdf
pdf: $(DOCNAME).pdf

# Rules
%.pdf: %.tex
    $(LATEXMK) -pdf -M -MP -MF $*.d $*

mostlyclean:
    $(LATEXMK) -silent -c
    $(RM) *.bbl

clean: mostlyclean
    $(LATEXMK) -silent -C
    $(RM) *.run.xml *.synctex.gz
    $(RM) *.d

.PHONY: all clean doc mostlyclean pdf

# Include auto-generated dependencies
-include *.d
```