# How to determine the exact compile process done by texstudio? (each command executed by texstudio to replicate the compilation in CLI)

Tags: compiling, texstudio, makefile

I have a fully working project in TeXstudio (and overleaf). I want to use makefile to recompile, and I am unable to figure out the exact sequence of commands TeXstudio uses in a full compilation process.

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  "main".tex
```

This does not create the same output when the bibtex and other aux files are cleaned.

Furthermore, I have tried using strace, but so far it has been unsuccessful. The surprising thing is, I can't even see syscalls related to executing a command.

I found [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370463/extract-syscall-names-from-strace-output) to list the system calls. And I opened texstudio,then started strace, run compilation and then stop strace.

```sh
strace -o >(awk '$1 ~ /^-----/ { toprint = !toprint; next } { if (toprint) print $NF }') \
  -c -p `pgrep texstudio` >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

And I could only recognize clone and clone3 syscalls related to running another command.

Here's the list of all syscalls made during the compile process

```
wait4
poll
readlink
clone
access
read
futex
writev
openat
ioctl
write
newfstatat
statx
clone3
mprotect
close
ppoll
mmap
fcntl
rt_sigprocmask
waitid
pipe2
rt_sigreturn
restart_syscall
getcwd
eventfd2
lseek
recvmsg
inotify_add_watch
inotify_rm_watch
```

Can someone help me figure out the whole compile cycle? This way or any other way (maybe by logs or just knowledge)?

Comment: Don't quote me on that but I believe TeXstudio inspects the log file and [dynamically runs other programs or TeX again](https://texstudio-org.github.io/compiling.html) accordingly. At least that's my experience. Unless, of course, you just choose one of the programs manually instead of the *magic* "Compile" >> button.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Is it to save time? If yes, then what is atleast the bootstrap commands when none of the temp files exist?

Because all the tools are CLI, but I can't find a way to use them in an actual terminal.

Comment: To save time? Sure, if it works correctly, it doesn't run something again unless it is needed. I don't know what you mean with "bootstrap command". Related: [Q64](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64), [Q40738](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40738) and probably the tag [tag:makefile]. Doesn't Overleaf try to do the same? I guess, TeX → glossaries → bibliographies → TeX → TeX seems to be a good start.

Comment: I just meant like the command that is run assuming the compilation is being run for the very first time and there are no other files than the source files

Comment: @ShrirajHegde I wouldn't try to replicate texstudio's convoluted compile sequence. I would use `latexmk` to compile your file, this will automatically determine which tools need to be run.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I this that is the right answer. I ran `latexmk -pdf` and it generated a PDF that are identical (verified with `diffpdf`)