# Write diagrams without a separate style file

Tags: diagrams

I have submitted a paper to a journal and it has been accepted. But after sending them the final tex.file for publication, today I have received the following message from them:

"Some of your equations are not appearing correctly because of your use of the separate style package {tikz}. Please format your equations and special characters using an equation editor such as MathType or Microsoft Equation Editor. Equations must be composed in the original document, not copied and pasted. Picture-type images cannot be used."

Indeed, I have written 6 diagrams in the tex file using the package {tikz}. Could anyone help me to rewrite these diagrams as the editors of the journal asked to do? I don't know even if the access to these equation editors are free or not, I never used them. Moreover from  a short searchit seems to me they are for word and not for tex.

Please help me with a suggestion or anything that I should do!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Best,
Sebastian

P. S. I have gotten one more message from them in which it is written that I " will need to create my equations without using the separate style file "tikz."  Our website does not recognize separate style files.

Please advice me how to do that!

I got one more message from them after asking for more explanations:

"Dear Dr. Burciu,

The pdf version of your manuscript was used for initial review purposes.  I have tried to render the TEX formatted version sent with your original submission and encounter the same error.

Separate style files are files such as TIKZ which our system does not recognize when coded into your TEX file.  When you write "usepackage TIKZ" our system does not recognize this command and cannot draw your equation.  All equations need to be created directly with TEX code.  Your command reads "\begin{tikzpicutre}" and our system does not recognize this command.  The equation needs to be drawn within the TEX format not with an input command for a picture.

I hope this is somewhat helpful.

Sincerely,
..........."

How can I draw pictures directly with the tex code without using style files?

Comment: TikZ is a "seperate style file"? What *isn't* a seperate style file? — Anyway, you can externalize (read: produce PDF files) from your TikZ pictures which can then be inserted as any PDF file in your document (chapter 50 "Externalization Library" in the PGFmanual). There is even a way so that you do not need to change your document that much by using only `tikzexternal.sty` (technically a "style file"), see section 50.5 "Using External Graphics Without PGF Installed". Related: [tag:tikz-external]

Comment: These requests seem very incoherent. Just to be clear, is the journal willing to accept TeX source at all? It seems so since they talk about your use of a package, but their "solution" is definitely not a TeX solution.

Comment: Yes, I have one more paper accepted to their journal and it was tex file, but without diagrams. Please helpe me what to do:) By the way, the journal is JMP.

Answer (score 5):

[American Institute of Physics journals](http://publishing.aip.org/authors/preparing-graphics) (I assume JMP means Journal of Mathematical Physics, after google-stalking you) require that graphics submissions be included as separate image files and not inline as TiKZ.

If your diagrams are graphics you can follow the advice [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46940/119); basically you separate out the TikZ part of the document, compile it separately into a PDF or EPS graphics file (following AIP's guidelines), and use `\includegraphics` to load it into your main document.

A quick browse of your publication record suggests that it is possible the diagrams you refer to are commutative diagrams. A random poke on the internet shows that [the above appears to be how other people dealt with the problem also](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/47/9/10.1063/1.2337848). (Quite clearly the commutative diagrams in the PDF version are included graphics, and not even in a vector format.)

One possibility, accepting that JMP does not support the use of the TikZ library, is that you can ask the editors whether they support the use of the (older) [AMScd](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amscd?lang=en) package. (<strike>I suspect they might since my papers in the JMP loaded style files from the AMS-LaTeX bundle and they didn't complain.</strike> They better since they make you use revtex which [requires AMS-LaTeX](http://journals.aps.org/revtex/)) If your commutative diagrams are simple enough they can be relatively quickly recreated using AMScd.

Otherwise, [Milne on his website](http://www.jmilne.org/not/CDGuide.html) lists a bunch of other options besides TikZ for creating commutative diagrams. (If you need diagonals, AMScd cannot help.) You can ask the editors at JMP which of the various packages listed they support, or send them a version of your manuscript each using a different one so they can test by trial and error.

Comment: Hmm... I should note that in many other cases the easiest thing would be to just re-submit the article with the relevant `.sty` file included in your submission. But TikZ has so many of them and it may be more hassle than it is worth.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thank you for your answer! Yes, the journal is Journal of Mathematical Physics and the diagrams are commutative diagrams. I will ask them which of the various packages presented on Milne's website  they support but I doubt that they will know automatically without testing a file.

Comment: Try first using the AMScd package; that has the highest chance of being accepted.

Comment: The tex file finally compiled correctly on their website using the  xy-Picture package!

Comment: Congrats! (And I will file this info away too in case I need it in the future.)