# Precompile header with xelatex

Tags: xetex, compiling, preamble

I read about precompiling the preamble in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15606/4918 and it worked fine with `pdflatex` but how can I do this for `xelatex`?

I tried

```
xelatex -ini -shell-escape -job-name="header" "&xelatex header.tex\dump"
```

but it ends with an error:

```
! Can't \dump a format with native fonts or font-mappings.
<*> &xelatex header.tex\dump
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem myself once. The first solution is of course, to take `\usepackage{fontspec}` out of the preamble document and put it right before `\begin{document}` in the main document.

But as you, just like me, want to load `fontspec` in a custom document class, you could use

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{STIXGeneral}
}
```

there. `\AtEndPreamble` works similar to the standard `LaTeX` command `\AtBeginDocument`, only that the code inside can itself use `\AtBeginDocument` like `fontspec` does.

Unfortunately this means that you can't cut the compile time of `fontspec` here. The same problem exists with `unicode-math` and `polyglossia` for example. (While I had no problems with `babel`.)

And here is an explanation as to why this is not possible, that I found on the [`XeTeX` mailing list](https://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2008-October/011090.html):

> > Jonathan Kew a écrit :
> >
> > > Right; this would present various technical challenges, and could be
> > > quite confusing for the user if the .fmt file contained references to
> > > fonts that meanwhile have been removed or modified in the host
> > > system.
> >
> > Ok. OTOH, I don't understand exactly how font preloading works for
> > "classical" TeX, but the same could happen if the fonts were removed
> > from the texmf tree (or even form the map files)? Or maybe TeX needs
> > only the tfms while XeTeX is using "more" of the font?
>
> Yes, that's basically the situation. With "classical" TeX, the .fmt
> file contains the entire tfm data for the preloaded fonts, so TeX can
> then do its work without reference to the tfms or any other files. (If
> you remove the tfms, it won't even notice as it already has that data.
> If you remove the pfbs or map file entries, TeX won't care, it can
> still typeset. Your output driver may have problems, though!)
>
> But for the equivalent to work with xetex, **we'd have to "embed" a
>
> large portion of the entire OpenType font into the .fmt file**. This
> doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: You should probably add explicitly to the format `\RequirePackage{expl3}` and other packages which `fontspec` loads.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll accept your answer although it doesn’t really answer my question but explains why there can’t be a better answer …

Comment: Maybe I'm too late to be here and gonna somewhat digress: I want to ask what is the difference between using `mylatex.ltx` (or `mylatexformat.ltx`) and not using it as in this post? Could anyone answer me?

Comment: 8 years later, most large packages end up loading something related to fontspec (Koma script classes do, tikz does, unicode-math and fontspec and polyglossia do of course, etc.).  As a result dumping isn't very effective at all for LuaLaTeX and XeTeX.

Answer (score 8):

Your preamble loads a ‘native’ (i.e. non TFM) font, which as the meessage says can't be dumped in the format. For example, just having `\usepackage{fontspec}` in your preamble will load Latin Modern OpenType fonts.

Comment: Do you mean that `fontspec` doesn’t work with precompiling headers?

Comment: Yes. `fontspec` used to have a `cm-default` option to disabling loading Latin Modern fonts, but that option is now gone.

Comment: I’m using other fonts than CM, so even this option won’t help :-(. So I get you right that there’s no way to precompile the preamble when using `fontspec` (`fontspec` is part of my own document class)?

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, you can ignore the errors, and all will work fine.

Here is an example file, to be saved as `test.tex`

```
%&test
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,graphicx,tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\endofdump
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
% this is a mistake in the map
%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55204/remapping-latex-symbol-to-another-unicode-value/55205
\AtBeginDocument{\let\setminus\smallsetminus}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
This is a test
\[ A\setminus B =  ∞ \]
\end{document}
```

then there is a Makefile

```
test.pdf: test.tex
    time xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex

test.fmt: test.tex
    time xetex -ini -interaction=nonstopmode -jobname="test" "&xelatex" mylatexformat.ltx test.tex
```

If you `make test.fmt` you will indeed see a lot of errors, but eventually the format file will be written; then `make test.pdf` will compile the `test.tex` without reloading all packages.

In my computer, compiling `test.tex` without using this trick takes ~3.8seconds, with this trick ~1.4seconds.

Comment: But this must have some drawbacks … the error couldn’t be there just for fun.

Comment: Yes Tobi, you are right, this does not work everytime, I am investigating...