# Remapping LaTeX symbol to another unicode value

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode, unicode-math, latin-modern

When compiling the following piece of LaTeX code, the ∖ symbol does not show up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
This will not show: $\setminus$ \\
This will show: $\smallsetminus$
\end{document}
```

I know why this happens: `\setminus` translates to unicode character `0x29F5`, and
this character is not part of Latin Modern Math. What I would like to do is to
use Unicode character for `\smallsetminus`, `0x2216`, instead. So what I am really
looking for is a way to remap the `\smallsetminus` command to another Unicode
value than the one defined by the unicode-math package. I know a possible way
to get a value for `\setminus` would be to use another math font that does have
Unicode character `0x29F5`. Adding the line

```
\setmathfont[range={"29F5}]{XITS Math}
```

gives me a ∖ symbol, but I don’t want to use another font for this
character.

Comment: Any reason y9ou can't just say `\def\setminus{\symbol{2216}}` or `renewcommand{\setminus}{\symbol{2216}}`?

Comment: The solution is in Caramdir's answer. `unicode-math` defines its commands only at `\begin{document}`, so any `\def` or `\let` statements before `\begin{document}` are overwritten (which is why the accepted solution is to wrap the `\let` in `\AtBeginDocument`)

Comment: Makes sense!  Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following makes `\setminus` equivalent to `\smallsetminus`:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\AtBeginDocument{\let\setminus\smallsetminus}

\begin{document}
  \[ A \setminus B \qquad A \smallsetminus B \]
\end{document}
```

The `\AtBeginDocument` is necessary because `unicode-math` defines its commands only at `\begin{document}`. So a simple `\let\setminus\smallsetminus` in the preamble would get overwritten. Alternatively, you could put `\let\setminus\smallsetminus` after `\begin{document}`, but this is a less “clean” solution as it violates the separation of content and styling.

If you want to use a completely different symbol, you can do something like

```
\AtBeginDocument{\def\setminus{-}}
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. I already tried \let\setminus\smallsetminus, but I didn't know that it was overwritten.

Comment: Thanks! And, it's a shame that this workaround is still needed in Nov '19 ...