# \setminus invisible

Tags: symbols, luatex

With Latin modern font, the symbol \setminus is invisible (I discovered, by chance, that it had gone from all my documents).
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}

\newfontface{\STIXTWO}{STIX Two Math}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\setminus}{}{\mbox{\STIXTWO\symbol{"029F5}}}


\begin{document}    
    $A\setminus B$  
\end{document}
```

So I tried `\newfontface` with StiX Two (thanks to an answer that egreg had given me for an another symbol problem) but it doesn't work.
What should I do?

Comment: unicode-math sets up lots of commands at begin document, so your redefinition is too early. move it, or use `\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}\setmathfont[range="29F5]{STIX Two Math}`

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140279/which-unicode-math-fonts-support-setminus

Comment: Thanks to both of you

Comment: Apart from the need of doing the redefinition `\AtBeginDocument`, you want `\mathbin{\text{\STIXTWO\symbol{"029F5}}}`, so the symbol has the correct spacings and scales in subscripts or subscripts.

Comment: Thank you @egreg, again. In the solution given by Ukrike, do I also have to correct the spacing?

Comment: @Didier No, in that case a math symbol is used with the correct spacing.

Comment: Ok, thanks @egreg

Comment: Could also be worth to try `\smallsetminus`, that exists in LM Math.

Comment: Thank you @Davislor It is not easy to choose a font. I chose Latin modern because it is one of the (very?) rare fonts which give rounded x and y in math mode

Comment: @Didier New Computer Modern has the same letter shapes. But that question is more about how to solve the bug you noticed.

Comment: Thank you@Davislor I checked the documentation of Computer Modern Font and I am not sure I understood correctly (my English is too poor). How do I load this font, if I want math-style=french and if I also want to avoid the warnings of mathtools ?

Answer (score 4):

The TeX Gyre fonts are missing this symbol.  This is a commonly-encountered bug, which `unicode-math` [didn’t fix back in 2011 because it was an upstream issue,](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/181) and then never implemented a workaround for, either.  It would, for example, be possible to check whether the current math font contains U+29F5, and remap if not, in a font-independent way.

You might want to set, near the top of your document,

```
\tracinglostchars=3
```

to make TeX treat missing characters as an error, instead of silently ignoring them.

Your options include:

- Load a font that has it, such as New Computer Modern (`\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}`)  This actually uses the `\smallsetminus` glyph for `\setminus`, however.
- Load this one symbol from a font that has it (`\setmathfont{Asana Math}[range=\setminus, Scale=MatchUppercase]`)
- Remap to another character, such as `\smallsetminus` or backslash (`\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\setminus}{\smallsetminus}}`)

Answer (score 3):

You might do it that way, but you get a symbol whose shape is not compatible with Latin Modern. An improved version would be

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}

\newfontface{\STIXTWO}{STIX Two Math}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\setminus}{}{\mathbin{\text{\STIXTWO\symbol{"029F5}}}}%
}


\begin{document}

$A\setminus B$

$x_{A\setminus B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

But a better solution for Latin Modern (and other fonts that miss the character) would be as follows.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\setminus}{}{\mathbin{\backslash}}%
}


\begin{document}    

$A\setminus B$

$x_{A\setminus B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]