# Using a custom .fmt with Emacs/AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex, format-files

I am attempting to use a plain TeX format, say, `foo.fmt` (based on XeTeX), with Emacs/AUCTeX (actually Aquamacs with built-in AUCTeX). I'm
unable to get AUCTeX to recognize the custom format. In TeXShop I
would  simply say:

```
% !TS-program=foo
```

I have tried various "Local Variables" such as

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-engine: foo
%%% End:
```

followed by <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd>. But so far nothing seems to work. TeXing stops with an error for an undefined command that was defined in `foo.fmt`. The format file is findable with kpsewhich. What am I missing?

Comment: Cross post: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/41080/620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that AUCTeX will use this kind of call:

```
Running `TeX' on `testfmt' with ``xetex  -file-line-error  --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" testfmt.tex''
```

Due to the `\input` a first line `%&foo`  to use `foo.fmt` format file is ignored, for example with this file:

```
%&foo
\foo
\bye
% Local variables:
% TeX-engine: xetex;
% End:
```

where macro  `\foo` was defined in the dumped `foo.fmt`.

You can see it originates in `"%'"` in `TeX-expand-list-builtin` and its usage in `TeX-command-list`

```
("TeX" "%(PDF)%(tex) %(file-line-error) %(extraopts) %`%S%(PDFout)%(mode)%' %t" TeX-run-TeX nil
  (plain-tex-mode ams-tex-mode texinfo-mode)
  :help "Run plain TeX")
```

I have customized the variable to contain this other entry

```
("texfmt" "%(PDF)%(tex) %(file-line-error) %(extraopts) %S%(PDFout)%(mode) %t" TeX-run-TeX nil
  (plain-tex-mode)
  :help "Fait (xe|lua|pdf)tex")
```

The only difference is I removed the `%'`. edit: I also removed the `` %` `` whose elisp definition makes it look like it is to be used paired with `%'` but this would need confirmation by  AUCTeX people.

Then when I open a buffer with file above I see in the menu "Command" a new entry `texfmt`. I choose that and xetex is run and uses the `foo.fmt`.

```
Running `texfmt' on `testfmt' with ``xetex  -file-line-error   -interaction=nonstopmode testfmt.tex''
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=foo)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./testfmt.tex [1] )
Output written on testfmt.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on testfmt.log.

TeX Output finished at Thu Apr 19 00:11:19
```

À propos formats with xelatex, not xetex, see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49295/precompile-header-with-xelatex) for a difficulty.