# Precompiled header in Lualatex on Windows?

Tags: luatex, windows

I am trying to typeset a longer document with lots of packages. Now it seems that pre-compiling the header can speed up the edit-compile-revise cycle quite a bit. I tried to follow the guideline from [How to speed up pdflatex for a very large document on MacOS X?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15604/how-to-speed-up-pdflatex-for-a-very-large-document-on-macos-x/15606#15606) but it does not work on my system and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

My preamble.tex looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\def\preambleloaded{Precompiled preamble loaded.}
```

and the main.tex file:

```
\def\ifundefined#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax} \ifundefined{preambleloaded}
\typeout{PRECOMILED PREAMBLE NOT LOADED}\input{preamble} \else
\typeout{\preambleloaded}
\fi

\begin{document}
test test test
\end{document}
```

Now after compiling the preamble with

```
lualatex -ini -job-name="main" "&lualatex preamble.tex\dump"
```

a main.fmt file is created and lualatex runs without errors. Compiling the main file with

```
lualatex -shell-escape main.tex
```

gives the message right at the beginning that the preamble was not included:

```
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
LuaTeX adaptation of babel <v3.8l-luatex-1.4> and hyphenation patterns for engl
ish, loaded.
PRECOMILED PREAMBLE NOT LOADED
(C:/Users/User/Documents/LaTeX/precompile/preamble.tex
(C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls 
...
```

The only difference that I can think of at the moment is that I am using LuaLaTeX on Windows 7 instead of pdftex on Mac OS X as in the linked question. Any hint how to fix this is very appreciated.

Comment: Don't you need: lualatex -shell-escape "&main main.tex" ?

Comment: @TacoHoekwater: Thank you! That works nicely. Could you convert your comment into an answer and maybe add a sentence what the difference is so that I can accept it?

Comment: For the general question (also seems to have more detailed answer) see [compiling - Speeding up compilation using precompiled preamble with LuaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114742/speeding-up-compilation-using-precompiled-preamble-with-luatex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need:

```
lualatex -shell-escape "&main main.tex"
```

otherwise the newly generated `main.fmt` file is not used at all.