# Speeding up compilation using precompiled preamble with LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, compiling, preamble, format-files

Compiling my documents with lualatex takes quite long. I have a complex preamble, and I noticed that it takes long to process this part of the file.

Today, I came across this website, which proposes a trick I haven't seen on this site before. By pre-compiling the preamble, it claims to speed up compilation approximately three-fold: [Faster LaTeX part IV: Use a precompiled preamble <sup>(Wayback Machine snapshot)</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20160912114941/http://www.howtotex.com:80/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-iv-use-a-precompiled-preamble/).

However, I have not been able to follow this tutorial with LuaLaTeX. How can I pre-compile my preamble with it?

Comment: If this trick works, it would be great to add it to the knowledge body of this stack exchange.

Comment: Lot of the time LuaTeX (luaotfload) spends on loading fonts. I am not sure if this can be put in the format.

Comment: I too think OpenType fonts can't be set up in a format.

Comment: You need the version of LuaTeX in TeXLive 2013; the one in TL2012 has a bug with `mylatexformat`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I get "Segmentation fault" if I try `mylatexformat` with `\usepackage{libertine}` before `\endofdump` (TL 2013/pretest)

Comment: @egreg: That [bug](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=746) should be fixed - plrease reopen the ticket and add more information.

Comment: @MartinSchröder *That* bug is fixed; but nothing there seems to say that OpenType fonts can be made part of the format. See [this ticket](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=825)

Comment: @topskip I suspect this is the answer: could you make it one? (I guess with advice to avoid any font stuff in a pre-compiled format).

Comment: @Ingo Not an answer to your question, but might be helpful in this context: You can use LuaJitTeX instead of LuaTeX. For many documents it can be used as a drop-in replacement. Depending on your use of Lua, this might yield a speed gain between 5% and 30%.

Comment: Do you use the `microtype`-package? In our case, this caused the largest performance drop (with LuaLaTeX).

Comment: @Marco I have tried running LuaJitTeX with my code, as it now ships with TeXLive 2014. However, it is not mature enough yet and fails to compile. @Andy disabling `microtype` surely helped!

Comment: It didn't help for me. Still pretty slow.

Comment: @Ingo You can set `microtype` up so that it is pretty quick (or disabled, can't remember) if `draft` is active and will automatically activate with `final`. However, this can cause changes to page breaks, so some care is required.

Comment: Crosslink: the general guide to precompile preamble is [compiling - Ultrafast PDFLaTeX with precompiling - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling) .

Answer (score 12):

I might be missing the point of the question, or fail to see why what my computer does is not what the OP is looking for. Further this is is certainly not the most elegant solution, since I'm at work so I only had Windows & TeXnicCenter+MikTEX2.9 at my disposal. But I think it does what it should.

Here's what I do:

1. Compile lua_pream.tex with profile `LuaTeX⇨PDF(pre)` (see below)
2. Compile lua_nopream.tex with profile `LuaTeX_post⇨PDF(post)`

**The profiles:**

`LuaTeX⇨PDF(pre)` is

```
luatex  -interaction=nonstopmode -ini -jobname="lua_pream" "&lualatex" mylatexformat.ltx "./lua_pream.tex"
```

or in TeXnicCenter:

[image]

`LuaTeX_post⇨PDF(post)` is

```
lualatex -fmt lua_pream "./lua_nopream.tex"
```

or in TeXnicCenter:

[image]

**lua_nopream.tex** contans not much really

```
\endofdump %%stuff from lua_pream.tex is dumped before here, you only need this if you have a local preamble
% part of the preamble that has to be evaluated each run
\begin{document}
The preamble used for this was compiled with vvvv set to \vvvv
\end{document}
```

**lua_pream.tex** contains the preamble

```
% static part of the preamble (stuff that does not change every now and then)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexbase}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\def\vvvv{foobar}
% the \endofdump part 'saves' everything above into one precompiled preamble, which gets loaded every time the LaTeX document is processed. This saves a lot of time mostly. 
% NOTE: the following line ends the dumping into the preamble format file!
\endofdump
\begin{document}
        This text plays no role I guess
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know so far this does not contain any actual LuaTeX specific stuff. I'm happy to work some in if requested.

Comment: You shouldn't have `inputenc` if you are using LuaTeX. And you probably don't want `fontenc` either, although it can be used if you know what you are doing. `hyperref` should be loaded late. It already loads `url`. Probably you want `fontspec`. I know this is only an example, but....

Comment: You're right. That is all simply copied from the link in the OP's question. I'll update it to more sensible code as soon as I find time. Feel free to go ahead and edit my post

Comment: applied your suggested changes