# How to precompile preamble when using arara

Tags: compiling, preamble, arara, format-files

A [different tex question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114742/speeding-up-compilation-using-precompiled-preamble-with-luatex) led me to a link regarding a [precompiled preamble](http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-iv-use-a-precompiled-preamble/).

I use arara for all of my runs.  What is the correct procedure to use a precompiled preamble for each of the runs made using the [`arara`](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/support/arara/doc/arara-usermanual.pdf) package?

Comment: Do you want it not to be used when run without `arara`?

Comment: To be honest, I probably jumped the gun. I saw the `%&mydoc` needs to be added to the top of the file, and wondered if it would poorly interact with the `arara` commands.  I'm working it out now that I've recently gotten some free time.