# how to compile without producing output

Tags: auxiliary-files

Is there any way to run LaTeX without it trying to produce output, only producing an `.aux` file with section, equation, table, figure, references, etcetera.  I understand it obviously can't produce page references.

I know about the virtues of `\includeonly`, externalization, etcetera; I'm not asking about anything other than the question above.

Comment: `pdflatex` knows the `--draft` option, which does not generate a `.pdf` output

Comment: You can also add  `\pdfdraftmode=1` to the document (which does the same as the command line option).

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15604/how-to-speed-up-pdflatex-for-a-very-large-document-on-macos-x/15607#15607

Comment: Thank you very much. This is actually not quite what I had in mind since it still appears to go through much of the processing and saves only about 30% off the compile time

Comment: @JPi Producing the `.aux` file requires typesetting the document anyway: how can the page numbers be found, otherwise?

Comment: I won't be referencing any pages or producing an index or table of contents so it doesn't matter to me whether or not the page numbers can be found.  From the feedback I'm getting here it sounds like it won't be easy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the draft mode:

```
-draftmode
          Sets \pdfdraftmode so pdfTeX doesn't write a PDF and 
          doesn't read any included images, thus speeding up execution.
```

`Arara` also supports it, here's an example for TeXworks:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { draft : yes }
```

I use the following snippet to compile a large document with hundreds of pages and references:

```
%!TEX TS-program = Arara
% arara: pdflatex: { draft : yes }
% arara: pdflatex: { draft : yes }
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is actually not quite what I had in mind since it still appears to go through much of the processing and saves only about 30% off the compile time.