# How to load precompiled preamble from a specific folder?

Tags: compiling, mac, preamble, format-files

According to this line [How to speed up pdflatex for a very large document on MacOS X?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15604/how-to-speed-up-pdflatex-for-a-very-large-document-on-macos-x/15606#15606) . Precompile preamble significantly speed up pdflatex compilation.

The method is to generate a `precompile.fmt` file( which is 6MB in my case), then copy it to the folder contains the tex file, and add `%&precompile` to the first line of tex file.

I did so, and found it really speed up the compilation. But since the `precompile.fmt` file is a little bit large. I think to copy it to every tex folder is really a waste of disk space. **So is there a way to load the same `precompile.fmt` file from the same location in different tex file?**

Comment: Go to the TeXShop Help Panel, select “Advanced Help” and then “Making and Using New TeX Formats”.

Comment: are you working on a mac, or on some other platform?  (if on a mac, tagging this question for that would be appropriate.)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I just figure out the way. Write the first line as `%& Path\precompile`

Comment: Well, sure.  I thought you were looking for an automatized solution.  Edit: but, after all, this is too. :-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti What do you mean by "automatized solution“? I am currently using texstudio

Comment: @user15964 -- i think that by "automatized solution" (i'd say "automated") is meant a solution in which it wouldn't be necessary to specify the location of the format file.

Comment: I am very busy during these days and I haven't got much time to visit TeX.SX: that's why I answer so late, please accept my apologies.  In this case, however, @barbarabeeton has already answered for me (and btw, yes, "automatizzato" sounds weird even in Italian! :-) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `precompile.fmt` file in the folder

```
~/Library/texmf/web2c/pdftex
```

creating the missing folders as you go.

On different TeX Live based distribution (the above path is good for MacTeX) the correct path would be

```
~/texmf/web2c/pdftex
```

(assuming the standard setup is used).