# Look for a tutorial for the "precompile" teXstudio option

Tags: miktex, compiling, texstudio, preamble

I assume that "precompile preamble" texStudio (advanced) option is meant to precompile a "preambule.tex" that is included before "begin{document}" in a "main.tex".

[Here is the reference I get for "precompiling"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15604/how-to-speed-up-pdflatex-for-a-very-large-document-on-macos-x/15606#15606)

I expected to get a "preamble.fmt" file in working directory but nothing. I'm working with miktex on windows 10.

I guess I'm not setting this option properly. I haven't found anything about this in texstudio documentation. Is there any tutorial somewhere about what is doing the texstudio precompile option and how to use it?

Comment: Any results from Dr. Google, Mrs. Youtube or from this places search box?

Comment: I just found one discussion about how to turn precompiling off if preamble is modified. In this post, author assume that reader know how to make it work. So I’m stuck at the beginning. Maybe I do not have the right keywords?