# Having the input and layout side by side

Tags: texshop, viewers

I have just installed latex on my mac. I opened the texwork and I can type in latex script there, whenever I compile it, I will get an output.

But is it possible to have the output instantly standing side by side, so that when I type, I can see the change immediately?

Do I have to get any other plugin?

Comment: That is not the way LaTeX is working.  It shows you after you complied the changed code the result, not simultanly ...

Comment: ok.. so I have to compile everytime. So is there a good way to set up the workspace? the happiest way to work with latex?

Comment: TexStudio provieds a layout which can arrange source and output beside each other an automatically updates the output on compilation. It has even a preview function http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/

Comment: More or less a duplicate of [Automatically start the necessary pdflatex runs if .tex has changed (MacOS X)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15342). For TeXShop, Claus Gerhardt's Flashmode approximates this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for a pseudo real-time LaTeX editor that can show the output and input side by side. If so, you can try [Bakoma](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/) as follows.

[image]

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that; it's a new development for sure.  I would add this answer (or edit the existing one) to reflect that in this question: [Is there any way to get real-time compilation for LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/633)